# Show column names from table as pascal case

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table in phpmyadmin with column names like `first_name`, `last_name`. When I use the command to show column names from the table, it displays them as `first_name`.

I want to display my column names like `First Name`. Can you please tell me how to show column names in pascal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code converts `some_text` to `Some Text`:

```
$before = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'something');

$after = array();
foreach($before as $v){
    $after[] = ucwords(implode(' ', explode('_', $v)));
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => First Name
    [1] => Last Name
    [2] => Something
)
```

---

And **another way** of doing the same:

```
// .. foreach ..
$after[] = implode(' ', array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', $v)));
// code
```

The output is the same as before.

---

---

The following example shows how to do it when running `SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLENAME`. I used PDO. Take a look:

```
$con = new PDO('con string here', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD');
$stmt = $con->prepare('SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename');
$stmt->execute();
$columns = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $columns[] = array(
        'original' => $row['Field'],
        'pascal' => ucwords(implode(' ', explode('_', $row['Field'])))
    );
}
```

The result of `$columns` will be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [original] => first_name
            [pascal] => First Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [original] => last_name
            [pascal] => Last Name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [original] => other_column
            [pascal] => Other Column
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [original] => something
            [pascal] => Something
        )

)
```

Comment: I have show column names by using this command:- show columns from tablename.